# Ada interfacing C++: instance destroyed

Tags: c++, oop, ada

I want to use a C++ library that implements the [Factory Method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) design pattern.

Below you can see a minimal reproducibable example, including C++ sources and the Ada adapter.

- Item.h:

  ```
  // Product interface

  #ifndef _ITEM_H_
  #define _ITEM_H_

  class Item {
  public:

    virtual ~Item() = default;
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
  };

  #endif
  ```
- ConcreteItem.h:

  ```
  #ifndef _CONCRETEITEM_H_
  #define _CONCRETEITEM_H_

  #include "Item.h"

  class ConcreteItem : public Item {
  public:
    ConcreteItem();
    ~ConcreteItem();
    void do_something();
  };

  #endif
  ```
- ConcreteItem.cpp:

  ```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include "ConcreteItem.h"

  void ConcreteItem::do_something() {
    std::cout << "Doing stuff \n";
  };

  ConcreteItem::ConcreteItem() {
    std::cout << "Concrete Item created \n";
  };

  ConcreteItem::~ConcreteItem(){
    std::cout << "Concrete Item destroyed \n";
  };
  ```
- Factory.h:

  ```
  #ifndef _FACTORY_H_
  #define _FACTORY_H_

  #include "Item.h"

  class Factory {
  public:
    static Item* get_configured_item ();
    Factory(Factory& other) = delete;

  private:

    static Factory* factory;
    static Item* config_item;

    Factory();
    ~Factory();
  };

  #endif
  ```
- Factory.cpp:

  ```
  #include "Factory.h"
  #include "ConcreteItem.h"

  Factory* Factory::factory = nullptr;
  Item* Factory::config_item = nullptr;

  Item *Factory::get_configured_item() {

    if (Factory::factory == nullptr) {
      Factory::factory = new Factory();

      if (Factory::config_item == nullptr) {
        Factory::config_item = new ConcreteItem();
      };
    };

    return Factory::config_item;
  };

  Factory::Factory(){};
  Factory::~Factory() {
    delete Factory::config_item;
  };
  ```

And here I have the Ada files that imports C++ symbols, generated with a call to `g++ -c -fdump-ada-spec -C ./Factory.h` and doing some modifications to suite my taste:

- Factory_h.ads:

  ```
  limited with Item_h;

  package Factory_h is

    type Factory is limited record
      null;
    end record
      with Import => True,
      Convention => CPP;

    function get_configured_item return access Item_h.Item'Class  -- ./Factory.h:9
      with Import => True, 
      Convention => CPP, 
      External_Name => "_ZN7Factory19get_configured_itemEv";

  end Factory_h;
  ```
- Item_h.ads:

  ```
  with Interfaces.C;

  package Item_h is
    type Item is limited interface
      with Import => True,
      Convention => CPP;

    --  procedure Delete_Item (this : access Item) is abstract;-- ./Item.h:8
    --  
    --  procedure Delete_And_Free_Item (this : access Item) is abstract; -- ./Item.h:8;

    procedure do_something (this : access Item) is abstract;  -- ./Item.h:9
  end Item_h;
  ```

And finaly an Ada main to test this silly example:

```
with Factory_h;
with Item_h;

procedure main is
  
  configured_item : constant access Item_h.Item'Class :=
    Factory_h.get_configured_item;
  
begin
  
  configured_item.do_something;

end main;
```

Do you know why if I comment out the Item primitives `Delete_Item` and `Delete_And_Free_Item` the call to `do_something` is never done and the item is destroyed?

If I uncomment them everything works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm far from expert on Ada-C++ interfacing, but my guess is that in the C++ code, do_something is the third entry in the virtual-function table for ConcreteItem. The dump-ada-spec operation adds Delete_Item and Delete_And_Free_Item to occupy the first two slots in the v-table on the Ada side, which makes do_something the third entry in the v-table, matching its position on the C++ side.

When you comment out Delete_Item and Delete_And_Free_Item this makes do_something be the first entry in the v-table on the Ada side. So when Ada calls do_something, it actually calls the first v-table entry, which on the C++ side is some other function -- apparently one that performs Delete_Item.

Comment: wow really? I didn't think that the declaring order would have a significance. Thank you! I'll wait some time before accepting it as an answer just in case someone has something more to say.

Comment: I've found the following link that enforces your comment [link] (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Interfacing-with-C_002b_002b-at-the-Class-Level.html) saying the following: ```Thanks to the compatibility between GNAT run-time structures and the C++ ABI, interfacing with these C++ classes is easy. The only requirement is that all the primitives and components must be declared exactly in the same order in the two languages.```